# Google Hangout algorithm to predict facial movements

Tags: algorithm, prediction, latency, google-prediction

Does anyone know where I can find the algorithm Google Hangout uses to predict facial movements? I need it for a University project. Would love to look at the source code of it.

I'm trying to find out how they reduce latency issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hangouts source code is closed, I doubt you can find it over the internet. You should look for an open source alternative, there are a lot of implementations of face tracking using OpenCV.